# Function to find a file or open a URL depending on argument?

Tags: find-file, url

**Q:** in there a function that can find a file or open a URL as needed?

I have a string that can be either a) a local filename, or b) a
URL.  Is there an existing function that I can call on the string
that will do what I mean and open the file if it's a file, or open
the URL in a browser if it's a URL?

It wouldn't be hard to write such a function, but I'd rather
not reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`browse-url.el` can easily be configured that way.

The following section of the doc of `browse-url-browser-function` is relevant:

> If the value is not a function it should be a list of pairs
>   (REGEXP . FUNCTION).  In this case the function called will be the one
>   associated with the first REGEXP which matches the current URL.  The
>   function is passed the URL and any other args of `browse-url'.  The last
>   regexp should probably be "." to specify a default browser.

Example configuration:

```el
(custom-set-default 'browse-url-browser-function
            '(("^/" . browse-url-emacs)
              ("\\`[^:]+\\'" . browse-url-emacs)
              ("\\`file://" . browse-url-emacs)
              ("." . browse-url-default-browser)))

(browse-url "/temp/test.txt") ;; opens in a new Emacs window

(let ((default-directory "/temp"))
  (browse-url "test.txt")) ;; opens the same file in Emacs window

(browse-url "file:///temp/test.txt") ;; opens the same file in Emacs window in read-only-mode

(browse-url "https://emacs.stackexchange.com") ;; opens in default browser
```